# Term for size of maximum independent set

Tags: graphs, terminology

An *independent set* is a set of vertices in a graph, no two of which are adjacent.

A maximum independent set is a largest independent set for a given graph G.

Is there a standard term for the size of the largest independent set in a given graph?

If not, what short term can you suggest for this size? Maybe "independence number"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called the **independence number** and it's usually denoted $\alpha(G)$.

Comment: This is probably the most common term. Another fairly common term is *stability number*, though this is used when referring to stable sets.